# Hide column dynamically depend on checkbox angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to hide rows depend on checkbox, using myfunction in ng-click to access dynamic values.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 $scope.jsonmain = ["brand","checkstatus","color","fabric","fit","package contents","size","sku","style","title","type","wash care"];
 $scope.myfunction = function (skip) {
  $scope.skip = !$scope.skip;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span ng-repeat = "skip in jsonmain">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="myfunction(skip)" type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{skip}}</input>
</span>
 <table style="border: 1px solid ;">
  <tr>
   <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;" ng-hide="{{display}}" ng-repeat= "display in jsonmain">
    {{display}}
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the flag used to show or hide items part of the object model, but you can't do this directly because `$scope.jsonmain` is an array of strings. If you are able to alter `$scope.jsonmain` so that it is an array of objects then you can skip the part of this example where it is loading the array of strings into an array of objects.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  $scope.jsonmain = ["brand", "checkstatus", "color", "fabric", "fit", "package contents", "size", "sku", "style", "title", "type", "wash care"];
  $scope.items = $scope.jsonmain.map(function(obj) {
    var newObj = {
      name: obj,
      display: true
    };
    return newObj;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items">
 <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.display" type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{item.name}}</label>
</span>
  <table style="border: 1px solid ;">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;" ng-show="item.display" ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```